# Rename folders containing a certain string

Tags: python, rename

I would like to use a Python script to look for folders containing a certain string in its name and replace the entirety of that name to another. Like this:

The data is nested inside folders LastName FirstName
The script should go to each of those folders and rename the following folders.

```
ep2d_diff_e_2d_tra_7
ep2d_diff_e_2d_tra_ADC_8
t1_blade_tra_darkfl_6
t1_blade_tra_darkfl_14
t2_blade_tra_320_9
t2_fl2d_tra_hemo_5
t2_tirm_tra_darkfluid_blade_4
```

to

```
DWI
ADC
T1
KM
T2
Hemo
Flair
```

Those numbers at the end are not always consistant so should just be dropped.

You can see those 2 are quite similar..The only difference being, that the one has a higher number in the postscript. (It might be 8 and 12 or other numbers)

```
t1_blade_tra_darkfl_6
t1_blade_tra_darkfl_14
```

How would I best go about it?

Comment: i don't understand the transition between the old name and the new one.
what exactly you want to do?

Comment: we're not writing code for you, show us what you've tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

The `os` package contains methods for manipulating files and folders, and you could use `re` to match the strings with regular expressions.

For example:

```
import os
import re

for dir_name in os.list_dir('path'):
    if re.match('string', dir_name):
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

You will find more info here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html